# How to get GPS coordinate debugging with simulator in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

I try to get coordinate of my location.

I stackoverflowed so what I coded is below:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

self.longitude=coordinate.longitude;
self.latitude=coordinate.latitude;

NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f",self.longitude);
NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", self.latitude);
```

But I'm always getting 0 all the time. Is the code above wrong? or
I didn't set my simulator for GPS location?

I don't understand why I'm having trouble in getting coordinate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, here are several issues in your code:

1. You should retain locationManager somewhere to keep it running
2. Implement `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` and `-locationManager:didFailWithError:` delegate methods
3. Also, if you are in iOS 8, you should add `[locationMamager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];` or `[locationMamager requestAlwaysAuthorization];`
4. Specify `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` accordingly in your Info.plist

You can simulate location using Xcode, look at the information from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html

Comment: After you did what Azat told you, you can simulate your current location by select Debug->Location->CustomLocation... when your app is running.

Comment: LoVo , you mean, debug -> simulate Location -> choose landmarks?

Comment: Azat, what does it mean 'Number 1' ? I did declare 'CLLocationManager *locationManager' and <CLLocationManagerDelegata>at controller.h interface file. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @LKM if `locationManager` is ivar or property of some class it is OK. If it is just automatic variable then location manager will be released after end of that method

Comment: @Azat I think I did all what you gave to me, but method didUpdateLocations is not called. And method didFailWithError, error.description says 'Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"' Can you configure it out? Thank you for giving me information. I studied a lot

Comment: @LKM have you enabled location simulation?

Comment: @Azat I believe it so. after building an app , check the landmark and do event!

Comment: @LKM did system show you message that your app is going to use location at first time you run your app? Have you allow access? And do you keep location manager working or switch it off after first fail? May be you switch on location simulation after location manager fails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72831/discussion-between-azat-and-lkm).

Answer (score 1):

`[CLLocationManager location]` will return you the most recently retrieved user location, but as the documentation says:

> The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.

At the beginning your location is still unknown. You should use the delegates methods to react when the CLLocationManager find out your location. Implement this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    //User your location...
}
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/location).

Comment: Thank you for you sincerity. Raspu, however, method didUpdateLocations is not called. I add key NSLocationWhenInUseUsage at info.plist

Answer (score 0):

```c
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status{
    BOOL shouldIAllow = FALSE;
    NSString* locationStatus = @"";

    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            locationStatus = @"Restricted Access to location";
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            locationStatus = @"User denied access to location";
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            locationStatus = @"Status not determined";
        default:
            locationStatus = @"Allowed to location Access";
            shouldIAllow = TRUE;
            break;
    }

    if (shouldIAllow) {
        NSLog(@"Location to Allowed");
        // Start location services
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Denied access: \(locationStatus)");
    }
}
```